# ExtJS Auto Resize Tab Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

We have a viewport, and inside it we have a *west region* for navigation tree and a *center region* for content (grids, forms, etc.) which has a *tab panel* inside it.

We dynamically add content (tabs) to this tab panel, on click of any sub-menu item in *navigation tree*.

These tabs are not re-sized on window re-size.

The function to add tabs dynamically is:

```
function AddNewTab(title, url, closable) {
    var tabs = Ext.getCmp('tabs');
    tabs.add({
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: title,
        closable: closable,
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        autoLoad: {
            url: url,
            scripts: true
        }
    });
    tabs.setActiveTab(tabs.items.length - 1);
}
```

**Update**:
This is the normal state where every things is OK
[image: This is the normal state where every things is OK]

But when we resize the window or collapse the right panel, tab panel won't re-size to fill the whole area.
[image: But when we resize the container, tab panel won't re-size to fill the whole area.]

Comment: What does `not resized` stands for?

Comment: We want auto-resizing feature, like viewport auto resizing. I can add some images.

Comment: Way too vague. How does it work now? How should it?

Comment: I see that the individual tabs get configured with `layout: 'fit'`, does your `tabpanel` itself have `layout: 'fit'` also?

Comment: Tabpanel layout defaults to `card` which implies `fit`. I agree that we need some images to see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout of the center region should be 'fit' .

Answer (score 1):

This helped me out.

```
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(myEvilPanel.doLayout, myEvilPanel);
```